# Team Explorer configuration via command line

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

I am trying to automatically configure the TF Workspace for all users when they login on a PC which is different from what they normally code on.

I am currently running the following to configure the workspace via a logon script
`./TF.exe workspace /new /collection:azuredevops.url/project /permission:public /location:Server /filetime:current /noprompt`

But when the user starts Visual Studio in Team Explorer it is not enabled /online for the user.
[image]

Even the "Connect to a project" is empty

[image]

How do I configure this in PowerShell or CMD using TF or any other function?

Comment: After executing the script, open VS and manually connect to the project, then go to check if the workspace created via the script is existing. And you also can try set **`/location`** as **`local`** in the tf command.

Comment: We want to be able to automatically set this because we cannot ensure that users remember the location or the address they need to enter. setting `/location` as `local` or `server` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Hi @Aasim Shakil Pathan, How are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

In the command line you are using, I see you set the value of the option **`/collection`** as "**azuredevops.url/project**".

According to the docs about **`tf workspace`** command (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=azure-devops)):

> **/collection: Specifies the project collection.**

It seems that the value of the option **`/collection`** should be set as the collection URL.

I tried both the collection URL and the project URL in the command, only the collection URL did work, the project URL returned error.

In addition, you can manually try the following command on the machine,

```
tf.exe workspace /new /collection:<collection URL>
```

to see if it can normally pop-up the window like as the screenshot shows below.
[image]

This can verify if the **`tf workspace`** command is working on your machine.

**[UPDATE]**

The **`TF.exe`** is a tool that integrates some interfaces of Azure DevOps. It helps you set up the configurations of TFVC workspace on background, instead of manually filling the parameters via the VS UI. It's not a VS integrating tool that can fill parameters on the VS UI.

When you open VS, to automatically connect the project on the VS UI, you need to use the VS integrating API (or interfaces collection) to achieve the operation on the VS UI. However, currently, we have no such API or CLI to do this. So, you need to manually connect the project after opening VS.

Comment: this does not help in any way, when VS is launched, the user still needs to connect to the Azure DevOps server in team explorer, and make it online.

Comment: @Aasim Shakil Pathan, I have updated my above answer with more detailed explanations. Please check it. Any questions, feel free to tell me.